# How to predict new data in Matlab neural network regression when output vs. target is not diagonal

Tags: regression, neural-networks, matlab, bias

In the ideal case, we expect the output vs. target plot to be diagonal. In Matlab, using the neural network regression app, the plot comes with the non-diagonal best fit (i.e., output=m x target+offset, where m is not 1).

In this case, when we predict new data using this trained model, wouldn't the result be biased? Should we transform the predicted value by the model to a new value using the equation above (output=m x target+offset)? Is it possible to compute the confidence interval of the original prediction as well as transformed prediction? I will highly appreciate your response. Many thanks.

One such plot can be found in the Matlab website (https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html). Screenshot:

[image: screenshot from Matlab website]

Comment: Well, I used the 'nftool', the same way the tutorial described in the above link. I have added the screenshot of the plot. As can be seen, the fit was very good with high R-square value, however, the prediction by the model will always be biased. If we are using this model, shouldn't we transform the prediction value based on the equation shown in the plot to remove such biased prediction? Is there any way to compute the confidence interval of the prediction?

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. My question is should we predict the new data and then transform using the equation shown in the plot, or simply ignore it?